# Use the UNIX epoch in a mysql column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, unix

A column in one of my tables is DATE and currently it gets automatically filled with a timestamp of when the row was made. The timestamp looks like 2013-02-10 19:56:12. Is there anyway I can have it timestamp with the unix epoch automatically? I hope this makes sense. I'm still a beginner when it comes to mysql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want *to project* (*select*) `TIMESTAMP` into `UNIX` format, use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)`

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date)
FROM tableName
```

- [UNIX_TIMESTAMP() <sup>MySQL Docs</sup>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)
- [SQLFiddle Demonstration](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5683/1)

Comment: thanks! is there a way I can do it in a php script? So if $date contains the timestamp can i do $newdate = mysql_query("SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP($date)") or something?

Comment: add an alias eg, `SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) unixFormat
FROM tableName` and on you php scipt get the value on `unixFormat`.

Comment: I see. is there a way I can add that query to my existing one? I want to select the last ten row so mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10"); my second column is the one with the timestamp.

Comment: and how are the tables related with each other? I mean on what columns will they be joined?

Comment: actually I figured out it the php strtotime() function works for what I need. thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [unix_timestamp](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/mysql-from-unixtime.php) function when retrieving data:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(timestampColumn)
```